# EntityFramework core not loading child entities after disposing the DbContext (and recreating it)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We're using EF core and I just learned that using the `DbContext` as long lived object is not a good idea. The `DbContext` is not designed to be a long lived object.

So I now inject a new instance for every transaction, which I thought worked great. But now I see that child entities are not being populated after disposing the `DbContext` and creating a new one.

Some example code to show the problem

```
        public InitialTestData(Func<IMachineRepository> machineRepositoryFactory)
        {
            {
                using var machineRepository = machineRepositoryFactory();
            
                if (!machineRepository.FindAll().Any())
                {
                    machineRepository.Add("411-01", "https://localhost:5002/411-01");
                    machineRepository.Add("411-02", "https://localhost:5002/411-02");
                    machineRepository.Add("411-03", "https://localhost:5002/411-03");
                    machineRepository.Add("413-01", "https://localhost:5002/413-01");
                    machineRepository.Add("413-02", "https://localhost:5002/413-02");
                    machineRepository.Add("413-03", "https://localhost:5002/413-03");
                    machineRepository.Save();

                    foreach (var machineEntity in machineRepository.FindAll())
                    {
                        var machineStatusChangeEntity = new MachineStatusChange
                        {
                            DateTime = DateTime.Now, 
                            State = MachineStateDataModel.Idle
                        };
                        machineEntity.StatusChanges.Add(machineStatusChangeEntity);
                        machineRepository.Save();
                    }
                }

                var bla = machineRepository.FindAll().ToList();
                foreach (var machine in bla)
                {
                    // machine entity has a list of one child entity as expected
                }
            }

            {
                using var machineRepository = machineRepositoryFactory();

                var bla = machineRepository.FindAll().ToList();
                foreach (var machine in bla)
                {
                    // machine entity has zero child entities, why? it's present in the database
                }
            }
        }
```

In the above example I (autofac) creates the machine repository twice. Each repository gets a DbContext injected. The first time, I add some entities and save the changes (persisted in database successfully). I can (obviously) still query on this repository, as everything is still cached as well.

But when I then recreate the machine repository for the second time, it is able to query the `Machine` entities (the "parent" entities) but it no longer is able to find the related child elements. As mentioned, they are stored in the database, I double checked the `Guid`s of parent and childs, the all match perfectly. Yet EF code doesn't "remake" the relation somehow.

Am I missing something important in the `OnModelConfiguring` (posted below) or did I design the entities wrong?

See below the remaining classes that make the "database layer"

Repository pattern:

```
    public class MachineRepository : RepositoryBase<Machine>, IMachineRepository
    {
        public MachineRepository(PatDatabase repositoryContext) : base(repositoryContext)
        {
        }       
    }

    public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class 
    {
        protected PatDatabase RepositoryContext { get; set; }

        protected RepositoryBase(PatDatabase repositoryContext) 
        {
            RepositoryContext = repositoryContext; 
        }
        
        public IQueryable<T> FindAll() => RepositoryContext.Set<T>();

        public IQueryable<T> FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) =>
            RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Where(expression);

        public EntityEntry<T> Refresh(T entity) => RepositoryContext.Entry(entity);

        public void Create(T entity) => RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        public void Update(T entity) => RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Update(entity);
        public void Delete(T entity) => RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Remove(entity);        
    }
```

The two entity classes

```
    [Table("Machine")]
    public class Machine
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string BaseUrl { get; set; }

        public ICollection<MachineStatusChange> StatusChanges { get; set; } = new List<MachineStatusChange>();
    }


    [Table("MachineStatusChange")]
    public record MachineStatusChange
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Machine))]
        public Guid MachineId { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

        public MachineStateDataModel State { get; set; }
        
        public Machine Machine { get; set; }
    }
```

The "PatDatabase" / DbContext

```
    public class PatDatabase : DbContext
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;

        // TODO, discuss/investigate
        // Any purpose to define DbSet<T> as they did in tutorial?
        //public DbSet<Machine> Machines { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Used by dotnet ef migrations
        /// NOTE: Autofac will always prefer the constructor with most arguments
        /// </summary>
        public PatDatabase()
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("IAI.ToolSuite.PAT.Server.appsettings.json");
            
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonStream(stream).Build();
            
            // TODO BP: replace "LocalMySqlConnection" with "MySqlConnection" when figured out migrations in docker properly
            // It seems that 'dotnet ef migrations remove' requires access to the database(??)
            // In my case, my docker-compose is down, I would expect that's not a problem.... To be investigated... 
            _connectionString = configuration["MySqlConnection:connectionString"];
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor used by autofac (autofac will always prefer constructor with most arguments if resolvable)
        /// </summary>
        public PatDatabase(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsLocal())
            {
                _connectionString = configuration["MySqlConnection:connectionString"];
            }
            else
            {
                _connectionString = configuration["MySqlConnection:connectionString"];
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// IMPORTANT
        /// override the OnConfiguring allows us to keep a parameterless constructor
        /// ef migrations tool requires a parameterless constructor
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(_connectionString, MySqlServerVersion.LatestSupportedServerVersion,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.EnableRetryOnFailure(20, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null);
                });
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Machine>().HasMany(m => m.StatusChanges);
            modelBuilder.Entity<MachineStatusChange>()
                .HasOne(m => m.Machine)
                .WithMany(m => m.StatusChanges);        
        }

        public void MigrateIfNeeded()
        {
            if (Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
            {
                Database.Migrate();
            }

            // I think calling ensure created before migrations can cause issues
            // when migrations exist but the database or tables were dropped
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In a glance, I could see that the line `modelBuilder.Entity<Machine>().HasMany(m => m.StatusChanges);` is not needed. You have derived a relation between the `Machine` and the `MachineStatusChange` with the `HasOne()`, `WithMany()`. Try removing the line and run. This duplicative relation may create the problem.

Comment: I should be downvoted a lot ;-). first in the exampe, I forgot to add `Include(m => m.StatusChanges)` so it obviously won't fetch the child entities. So a very poor job of providing a reproducing scenario....

Comment: However, my actual problem was equally stupid. I did this: `var machines = machineRepository.FindAll();` followed by the next line: `machines.Include(m => m.StatusChanges);`. I didn't capture the resulting IQueryable...... And then on the next line, I would iterate over the original `machines` variable, who knew nothing about the `Include`. This took me 2 hours to figure out. Completely looking in the wrong direction.....

Answer (score 0):

Argh... I wasn't including the child entities at all after disposing it...

My apologies for wasting anybodies time.

The obvious fix

`var bla = machineRepository.FindAll().Include(m => m.StatusChanges).ToList();`

My actual problem which I had was this

```
    using var machineRepository = _machineRepositoryFactory();
    var machines = machineRepository
        .FindAll();
    
    // Here, it would've had been a GREAT idea to
    // capture the resulting IQueryable return by `Include`
    machines
        .Include(m => m.StatusChanges)

    // Iterating over machines now, will obviously not include the child entities.
```

So the fix...

```
    machine = machines
        .Include(m => m.StatusChanges)
```

Or even simpler of course...

```
    using var machineRepository = _machineRepositoryFactory();
    var machines = machineRepository
        .FindAll()
        .Include(m => m.StatusChanges);
```